# Remove duplicate column in 2D array

Tags: python, list, function, call

broken down to maximum simplicity:

I have list

```
a=[1,2,3]
```

then I call a function

```
funct(other variables,...,a)
```

In the function I do something like:

```
if x:
    b= np.delete(b,a)
if y: 
    b=a
```

but I get a Value error from the file calling the function:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 3)

The error points to the variable a. 
It seems to me that the information about a is somewhere lost. Could that be. Do I have to declare it differently if I assign it  to a function? Interestingly I do the same with another variable and this does function. 
Nothing is done to a inbetween.

Before the function was a separate file where I declared a the same way. It worked. Now I cahnged the file into a function and simply creat a in a diifernt file as before and send it to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me,

the return in the function had less variables than stated in the calling function.
This was a copy paste leftover.

Because the function itselve called the error, it pointed to the last line of the function leading me to think the problem would be the last variable.